# If condition does not work

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get the value of entity which is inside json array. I have used the object `subMenuObject` to get and store the json response data. In my code I have used,

```
Log.i("MealDealCatCode ", subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode"));
```

and it prints `L3` in my logcat.

My problem is I have used a `if` condtion as,

```
if ((subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode")).equals("L3")) {
```

When I debug and try to go inside the `if` condition it doesn't go in. It check that and skip the if condition. What is the problem in my if condition. Any help will be highly appreciated.

code used to access the value

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

    JSONArray subMenuArray = object.getJSONArray("MealDealItemEntity");

    for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
        JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray.getJSONObject(j);

        Log.i("MealDealCatCode ", subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode"));

        if ((subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode")).equals("L3")) {
            Log.i("MainMenuDescription", subMenuObject.getString("MainMenuDescription"));
        }
    }
}
```

`json` response:

```
{  
     "MealDealItemEntity":[  
         {  
            "MealDealCatCode":"L3  ",
            "MainMenuDescription":"Jumbo Coca Cola 199 Rs. 0.00",
         }
      ],
      "MealDealCatCode":"L3  "
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it contains **spaces**.

Try this instead:

```
if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim().equals("L3")) {
```

The `trim()` function removes the spaces.

Comment: Thanks that worked but I think malarres gave the answer 1st. So I think iI have to vote for him

Comment: Your answer is well completed answer. Yh I saw the time difference. I voted for the 1st correct  answer. I'm new to this system, is it possible for me to vote for 2 answers?

Comment: No, you can't. There's only 1 accepted answer. You judge which is the best one.

Comment: I voted for u since your answer is complete and correct answer.

Comment: oh don't worry for who answered first. just be kind with future readers (that's what you did) And remember that you  can upvote as well (that's what i did with golem's answer) so in the future someone will see the question and will have a hint on what response is the best to start with

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add a `.trim()`